# Wordpress administrative panel customization

Tags: php, wordpress

In the wordpress ADM panel I have a menu item that is called the client area. I have put category types for when the user is going to publish some document. He / she reports what type of document is Ex: Financial, Plants, Announcements, Contracts etc. The customer asked for these categories to appear as a sub-menu and from there he chose the category of the document. Example in the image I have Client Area and as submenus add Documents and Categories Documents

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZJzW.png)

I will need to customize so that the menu is as follows
add documents Categories Financial Documents Plants Press Releases Contracts
And from these submenus it will sign each item if it is financial all financial and so on.

Is there a way to customize this in Wordpress?

Comment: Do you mean archive page for all posts in category?

Comment: Today, the posts are all together in the client area independent of the category he clicks to add new document and selects a category to which that document will belong, but everything is mixed there in the panel, I would like to know if there is any way to separate them by categories creating a page type for each category type, but within the Post Types area of ​​the client

Comment: If you go to taxonomy of category (Categories Documents) you see all categories with number count eg: "Category  Name (2)".

Just click on the number counting and you get page with category filter.

Now if u want you can add custom link under the post type menu for quick navigate.

Comment: How do I create a custom link in the menu? Is it possible to put these categories as custom menu in taxenomy documents? Send me a template link so I can learn, thanks for the help

Comment: This link explain how to mange wp admin menu: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/266319/119573

and this is a category posts link example on tax named product_category and products cpt: 
`/wp-admin/edit.php?product-category=gadgets&post_type=product`

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed, I just needed a template.
One last question in the Category taxonomy when I click on the category number count
it returns me only 1 post in the category and in some it does not retake me even if it has posts registered in the category
Do you know what it can be? Thanks again.
Post the link as a solution so I can close the topic

Comment: Do you assign the term to post?

Comment: Yes, but I already discovered where the error was, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add and [mange wp admin menu](https:///wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/266319/119573).

For example you will need add links to terms posts filter.
You can get the relavante url structure from a category posts link go to taxonomy of category (Categories Documents) you see all categories with number count eg: "Category Name (2)".

Just click on the number counting and you get page with category filter.

For example on tax named "product_category", term named "gadgets" and "products" cpt:
`/wp-admin/edit.php?product-category=gadgets&post_type=produc‌​t`